# ¿Tego problemas al publicar web services?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mvc, web, servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]llevo mucho días con este sin poder solucionarlo. he creado un WS en Vs2015,lo he probado en local y funciona correctamente, pero al publicarlo en IIS, me muestra error al consumirlo.

adjunto codigo de WS:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.EntityClient
Imports EinsaDAO

' Para permitir que se llame a este servicio web desde un script, usando ASP.NET AJAX, quite la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="https://mi dominio.es/")>
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class WS_INVECPRO1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    '<WebMethod()>
    'Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    '    Return "Hola a todos"
    'End Function
    
        <WebMethod>
        Public Function lstPersonal() As List(Of cPersonal)
            Dim lst As New List(Of cPersonal)
    
            lst = (From c In PersonalDL.listaAlta Select New cPersonal With {.IDPersonal = c.idPersonal, .NumPersonal = c.NumeroPersonal,
                    .Nombres = c.NombreApellidos}).ToList
            Return lst
    
        End Function
    
 

   <WebMethod>
    Public Function getPersonalxNpersonal(sNum As String) As cPersonal
        Dim oPersonal As New cPersonal


        Dim obj = PersonalDL.getXNumPersonal(sNum)
        If obj IsNot Nothing Then
            oPersonal.IDPersonal = obj.idPersonal
            oPersonal.NumPersonal = oPersonal.NumPersonal
            oPersonal.Apellidos = obj.NombreApellidos

            End If
    
   

   c.NumeroPersonal,
        Return oPersonal

    End Function

End Class
```

El error que muestra al consumirlo, una vez publicado en IIS, no obstante en este servidor web tengo varias web que están funcionando bien, solo tengo problemas con este web service, que es el primero con lo que estoy trabajando a modo de prueba. alguien que me pueda ayudar con este error por favor. muchas gracias por adelantado

---

[![este es el error que me sale al compilar web service, he añadido en el webconfig esta lineas:

```
<AppSettings>
    <add key="user" value="test"/>
    <add key="pass" value="test2020"/>
  </AppSettings>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el codigo tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguien que me pueda ayudar:

Comment: Y el error que muestra al consumirlo es......?

Comment: Hola Yussef, acabo de adjuntar el pantallazo.

Comment: Si es un dominio web en ese servidor iis, ya configuraste el certificado ssl en los enlaces del sitio (HTTPS Bindings)? Además, pon la parte donde consumes el ws, para ver si tu config de SecurityProtocol es la correcta

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funciona, he quitado el SSl y va bien. ahora el problema que tengo es al introducir la autenticacion por soapHeader. he agregado en el web config:  
<AppSettings>
    <add key="user" value="test"/>
    <add key="pass" value="test2020"/>
  </AppSettings>